# How to add customized navigation in MVVM navigation in xamarin native

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, mvvm-light, xamarin.windows

I am using xamarin native and I want to do different transition for xamarin MVVM navigation during push and pop I want  to do custom navigation like page curl,flip,rotate etc

So far what I could achieve is to either stop using the existing transition like push and pop but I couldn't find any way to introduce different navigation in place of that in MVVM navigaiton

But I don't have any idea how to do that.

Any help would be appreciated !